# MySQL SELECT give empty result until server restart

Tags: mysql, empty-list

I have query to find any special operations on db:

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl_oper
WHERE id_oper_tip = 8 AND id_oper_naim = 6
```

and this query return empty set.
But another query:

```
SELECT
    id_oper_naim,
    id_oper_tip
FROM tbl_oper
WHERE id = 34855
```

return

```
+--------------+-------------+
| id_oper_naim | id_oper_tip |
+--------------+-------------+
|            6 |           8 |
+--------------+-------------+
```

After MySQL daemon restart, first query return

```
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 23129 |
| 23482 |
| 23483 |
| 23915 |
| 24274 |
| 24417 |
  ...
| 34855 |
+-------+
```

What is the reason of strange behavior? Why first query return empty result without daemon restarting?

Comment: Do you run the query in the same session? E.g. the same window in workbench? Or do you run one in phpmyadmin and one from your php-scripts? It might be a transaction problem. Or maybe you were executing one of the scripts in a different database by accident. Does this problem persists?

Comment: query running on same session from IDE (PhpStorm). Identical result when run in terminal. Problem is not persists. Some time (days, week) script is work fine, then break. There is one database only.

Comment: Well, it should not happen, and from your information, it's hard to guess what might went wrong here, since these querys alone should obviously work correctly. You use replication? Are these columns all integers? (Maybe it's a cast problem. Do you get a warning or an error message?). I would check your error log (though I doubt there is a problem here, since you get an (empty) result). Enable the [general log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html), and the next time the problem occurs, try to figure out what happens around/before your query, especially with your `tbl_oper`.